# Cannot GET error while returning response

Tags: json, node.js, express

I am creating a script using `node.js`,`fbgraph` api and express framework. I POST `access_token` of user from a page `index.html` on nodejs server. I am able to retrieve the `access_token` and I used the fbgraph api to retrieve further user info. But when i try to send the response Json object i am getting this error `Cannot GET /`.
Here are my code ,  I am not able to understand where is problem coming , everything seems to work. I checked other questions also , they are not helpful in my case, I dont need to show any template. I only want to return response.

NOTE: In my project folder file structure s like this :-

```
node_modules
app.js
package.json
```

CODE:  `app.js`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var graph = require('fbgraph');
var app = express();





    app.use(bodyParser());
//Retrieve POST data
    app.post('/', function(req, res) {
        // console.log(req.body.access_token);
        var access_token = req.body.access_token;
        //set access token
        graph.setAccessToken(access_token);
        //Graph Api request
        graph.get("/me?access_token="+access_token, function(err, b_res) {
           // console.log(b_res)
            var name = b_res.name;
            var id = b_res.id;
            var profileUrl = b_res.link;
            //Retrieve profile url
            graph.get("/"+id+"/?fields=picture", function(err, g_res) {
                //JSON object to be returned
                var userObj = {
                    "name": name,
                    "id": id,
                    "profilerl": profileUrl,
                    "picurl": g_res.picture.data.url
                };
                console.log(userObj);
                res.json(userObj);
                  //res.send(userObj);
            });
        });

    });
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

Comment: Where you want to send your json object ? or you want to display it on the front end ?

Comment: I want to send the Json object to same page index.html  , So that i can retrieve it using ajax. Basically i want to create a script , if someurl send POST request with access_token on node.js server , it returns  the Json object response on same url.

Comment: You can perform db operations here in the same page when you get object in userObj and send its result to some html page like this
res.render('views/index', {data: dataAfterDbOpeations})

Comment: I am getting the hint, i need to send json object to some view.For example , if create a directory in project folder named public/index.html  , Somehow i send the json object to that html page. It will work. Thanks for your reply. I will notify the result.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in above comments you can perform db operations here in the same page using userObj attributes in where clause or whatever other operation you want and then pass db returned object in the view like this

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var graph = require('fbgraph');
var app = express();





app.use(bodyParser());
//Retrieve POST data
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    // console.log(req.body.access_token);
    var access_token = req.body.access_token;
    //set access token
    graph.setAccessToken(access_token);
    //Graph Api request
    graph.get("/me?access_token="+access_token, function(err, b_res) {
       // console.log(b_res)
        var name = b_res.name;
        var id = b_res.id;
        var profileUrl = b_res.link;
        //Retrieve profile url
        graph.get("/"+id+"/?fields=picture", function(err, g_res) {
            //JSON object to be returned
            var userObj = {
                "name": name,
                "id": id,
                "profilerl": profileUrl,
                "picurl": g_res.picture.data.url
            };
            console.log(userObj);
              //res.json(userObj);
              //res.send(userObj);

            //perform db operation using userObj and when you get the returned object from db pass it to the view. Let say dataAfterDbOpeations is the returned object of ur query

            res.render('views/index', {data: dataAfterDbOpeations})

        });
    });

});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000); 

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'));
```